# How to prevent duplicate data in SQLite3 in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to prevent duplicate values in SQlite DB.These are essentially a list of names along with which I am storing date as  `NSString` as well.Now what I want to do is , insert a name only once and if inserted second time I want to update the date for it?So far I am able to insert new record, however not able to update it.What am I missing?

```
 -(NSString *)viewDataBaseForCity:(NSString *)cityName addedDate:(NSString *)dateAdded{

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT cityname FROM CITIES WHERE cityname=%@", cityName];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
         //This part is not executed at all               

        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            self.tempcityName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            NSLog(@"Found city name : -%@",self.tempcityName);
            return self.tempcityName;

        }else{

            NSLog(@"Not Found");
            return nil;
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(citiesDB);
    }

}
return nil;

 }

 -(void)checkforupdate:(NSString *)cityName addedDate:(NSString *)dateAdded{
 {
if(tempcityName == cityName)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE CITIES set id=%@ WHERE cityname=%@", dateAdded, cityName];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

    {
        NSLog(@"updated successfully");
    }


    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(citiesDB);
}
else
{
    [self insertintotable:cityName addedDate:dateAdded];
}
}
}

 -(void)insertintotable:(NSString *)cityName addedDate:(NSString *)dateAdded{
 {

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insert_sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CITIES(cityname,id)VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\")",cityName,dateAdded];


        const char *insert_stmt = [insert_sql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
        { 
            NSLog(@"Saved");      

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"NOT Saved");    

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(citiesDB);
}
}

}
```

Now the fields of table are created as below.

```
  - (void)initDatabase{

//Putting in caches

NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                      (NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [cacheDir
                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CityList.db"];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];



if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO) {
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK) {


        char *errMsg;
        NSString *sql_stmt = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CITIES (";

        sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"cityname TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, "];

        sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"id TEXT)"];

        if (sqlite3_exec(citiesDB, [sql_stmt UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg)!=SQLITE_OK)   {

            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"CITIES table created successfully");
        }

        sqlite3_close(citiesDB);

    }else {

        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
   }

   }
```

Comment: When you are inserting the name for second time, you want to update the date of already existing row date or you want to insert a new row and then insert the date.

Comment: I want to update the date of existing entry/row.

Comment: updated the answer.. Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will help you to do what you want. First check for the cityname you are entering if it exists in database table then update if not exists just insert into the database table.

```
@synthesis tempcityName;

-(BOOL)saveCity:(NSString *)cityName addedDate:(NSString *)dateAdded{

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT cityname FROM CITIES WHERE cityname=%@", cityName];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            tempcityName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

        }

        else{
        [self.insertintotable:cityName];
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(citiesDB);
[self.checkforupdate:cityName];
}
```

To check the data is eligible to update or not:

```
-(void)checkforupdate:(NSString *)cityName
{
if(tempcityName == cityName)
{
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE CITIES set id=%@ WHERE cityname=%@", dateAdded, cityName];

const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_beaconDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

{
NSLog(@"updated successfully");
}

sqlite3_finalize(query_stmt);
sqlite3_close(citiesDB);
}
else
{
[self.insertintotable:cityName];
}
}
```

If the data is not eligible to update then call to insert in DB table

```
-(void)insertintotable:(NSString *)cityName
{
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK) {


//This inserts same name multiple times.
NSString *insert_sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CITIES(cityname,id)VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\")",cityName,dateAdded];


const char *insert_stmt = [insert_sql UTF8String];
sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) 
{ 
NSLog(@"Saved");      
return YES;
}
else{
NSLog(@"NOT Saved");    
return NO;
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(citiesDB);
}
```

Comment: Hi .I have updated code according to your solution.Now I am getting "Insert Successful" and "Insert Failed(if tried repeatedly the same name)" .....only.But I am not getting "Updated Successfully"...Can you please take a look.

Comment: I think you are creating database in different paths for every cal of the method

Comment: Tried your Solution.The sqlite_prepare statemnt doen't get executed during checking for particular name i.e during 'Select query'

Answer (score 0):

First try to update the date.
If this fails (i.e., if [sqlite3_changes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) says no rows were modified), insert a new row:

```
execute("UPDATE Cities SET id = ? where cityname = ?", ...);
if (sqlite3_changes(citiesDB) == 0) {
    execute("INSERT INTO Cities(cityname, id) VALUES(?,?)", ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you retrieve all data of name from table using Retrieve Query.

```
  if ([RetriveDat containsObject:@"New Data"])
      {    
         // Update Quert
      }
    else
      {
         // Insert Query
      }
```